# Parallel processing and synchronization using semaphores in C

Tags: c, unix, parallel-processing, fork, posix

#### Questions:

1. Are my processes running in parallel?
   *I want six processes running in parallel.*
2. How can I sync these processes (parent with five child processes) using semaphores, in an infinite loop? So the output would be: 1 2 3 4 5 reset 1 2 3 4 5 reset etc...
3. Any simple and understanding semaphore documentation?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

parentWithFiveChildren()
{   
    printf("1 "); //Parent
    fflush(stdout);

    int i, status;

    for (i = 2; i < 7; i++)
    {   
        sleep(1); 
        if (fork() == 0) //Child Processes
        {               
            if (i == 6) 
            {
                printf("reset "); 
                fflush(stdout);
                exit(0);
            }
            printf("%d ", i); 
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(7); 
            exit(i); //Exiting child processes
        }
    }

    while ((wait(&status)) > 0)
    printf("\a");
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    parentWithFiveChildren();
}
```

#### Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 reset
```

Comment: The answer to these questions lies outside of the realm of C and in the realm of POSIX (as you would know if you had clicked on the 'fork' tag to read the tag wiki), among other things. Do you have six processor cores? If not, is it even possible to simultaneously run six processes, as opposed to task-switching between them? I hope this comment has provided enough food for thought for you to go off and do some research and come up with answers on your own. If that's all too easy for you, then consider that "premature optimisation is the root of all evil" and ask yourself, why `fork()`?

Comment: @Seb - _The answer to these questions lies outside of the realm of C and in the realm of POSIX_.  1) maybe, but considering the context question, and experience level of asker, 2) and 3) are well inside the realm of C.

Comment: @ryyker Regarding 2, C doesn't define the term "process"; that's also a POSIXism.

Comment: Is there really something here that  indicates a downvote, or a close vote?  The question is well formatted, well formed, has some level of specificity, and can possibly be useful to others in the future.  Should there not be some consideration on experience of poster to both the site and to the craft?

Comment: @ryyker: I've added [tag:posix] and [tag:unix] tags to obviate the somewhat unnecessarily pedantic objections that "this isn't pure standard C", though the [tag:fork] already did that.  I agree that this is a reasonably well presented question asking an answerable (not too broad) question.

Comment: @Seb My professor told me to use fork().

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. Parallelism

No, the processes are not running in parallel (or, at least, they're only running in parallel transiently, and only two processes at a time), **but** that's only because:

1. The `sleep(1)` gives the parent process a long time (at least a second) doing nothing.
2. The child finishes and exits during that second.

Your printing code in the child is odd; there is effectively no difference between the `i == 6` and the other operations.  In `main()`, `return 0;` and `exit(0);` are practically the same — there can be differences, but they're obscure and not germane to your code.

You should `#include <sys/wait.h>` and you should collect the dead children's PID (and status); it would make things clearer to you.

You could also have the children report sleep for a while (say 7 seconds each).  That would give you all the child processes 'running' (actually, sleeping) in parallel, and the parent then waits for the children to exit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("[PARENT] with pid %d\n", getpid()); 
    fflush(stdout);

    for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++)  // Odd loop conditions, but not wrong
    {   
        sleep(1); 
        if (fork() == 0)
        {   
            printf("[CHILD] with pid %d from parent with pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); 
            fflush(stdout);
            sleep(7);
            printf("[CHILD] with pid %d exiting with status %d\n", getpid(), i); 
            exit(i);
        }
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), corpse, status);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./test-forking
[PARENT] with pid 13904
[CHILD] with pid 13905 from parent with pid 13904
[CHILD] with pid 13906 from parent with pid 13904
[CHILD] with pid 13907 from parent with pid 13904
[CHILD] with pid 13908 from parent with pid 13904
[CHILD] with pid 13909 from parent with pid 13904
[CHILD] with pid 13905 exiting with status 2
13904: child 13905 exited with status 0x0200
[CHILD] with pid 13906 exiting with status 3
13904: child 13906 exited with status 0x0300
[CHILD] with pid 13907 exiting with status 4
13904: child 13907 exited with status 0x0400
[CHILD] with pid 13908 exiting with status 5
13904: child 13908 exited with status 0x0500
[CHILD] with pid 13909 exiting with status 6
13904: child 13909 exited with status 0x0600
$
```

An upgrade to the code would print the time with each line of output too.

#### 2. Killing

Any of the processes (in the set created by the parent) can kill any other process (in the set) that it knows about, using the `kill()` system call.  It really isn't clear whether you want the first child or the last child to kill the parent, or something else.  If the first child kills the parent, the first child will be the only child (because of the delays).  It also isn't clear why you want to send signals between the processes.

#### 3. Looping

Yes, you could do something — the question is, what are you really after.  Simply printing `parent` and `child` multiple times doesn't require multiple processes.  If you want the parent to say "I'm here", and each child to say "I'm here" periodically, you need to have the children looping and sleeping, and the parent looping and sleeping after all the children have been created.  Not hard to do.

Comment: "The *any of the processes* can kill any other process it knows about using the `kill()` system call." -- the blooper of the Jonathan Leffler. ;)

Comment: @Seb: what's the problem? (I've fixed "The any" to "Any".) If one of the processes knows the PID of another process in the set, it can send a signal via `kill()`. The parent could send a signal to any of child; any child could send a signal to the parent. It is harder for the children to send signals to each other, but if the system is as idle as mine was, they can guess the PIDs of the other children. If they choose a PID they're not related to, the signal will fail, but the discussion is meant to be limited to the set of processes created by the parent (I'll grant you that could be clearer).

Comment: _sleeping_ is not mutually exclusive to _running_, is it?  I would say all threads that _exist_ are also _running, whether asleep or active, and therefore, running in parallel with each other.  Please explain why you say they are not in parallel.

Comment: @ryyker: In the original code in the question, the first child has exited long before the second child is created, which is not 'running in parallel' by any meaningful definition of 'running in parallel' that I know of.  It would not take much to make it so the processes are 'running' (at least, in existence) at the same time; a sleep in the children is sufficient, as my modified code shows. In my experience, sleeping is not the same as running, but processes exist in parallel whether sleeping or running — but not once exited. Unwaited-for processes become zombies, of course, until waited for.

Comment: Good. Now the only issue left is the grammatical error: "Any of the processes ... that it knows about ..."; you're talking about a group of processes as though it's a singular. The way you explained it in your response to me seems grammatically correct.

Comment: @Seb: I think it is grammatically correct now. _Any [one] of the processes … can kill any other process … that it knows about …_ — the 'it' refers to the 'any [one]'.  The 'one' isn't present in the text but is the normal meaning of 'any of the processes', I think.

Comment: You're right. In the context you've provided, "Any of the processes" does imply "Any one of the processes". It's still a little ambiguous until the eye comes across the keyword "it" and the brain realises that it's a singular item from the set of processes; up until that point in time someone might just as easily read this as "Any [six] of the processes...", so it still reads a bit awkwardly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler According to question three, i wanted to print a pattern like this in an infinite loop, _1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc..._ 1 is the parent, 2-6 are child processes. The issue is that I must use only six processes.

Comment: OK; so create the processes, and then let them run in a loop.  How fast do you want the numbers to appear?  One a second?  More frequently?  If you're going to allow once a second, it's relatively simple.  If you want it to go faster, you'll have to work out how you're going to do the synchronization between the processes — which depends, in part, on which mechanisms you've been taught so far.

Answer (score 2):

question 3). *...Can I put main function in an infinite loop...*?

***Sure you can***:

```
int  main(void)
{
    int c=0;
    while((c != 'q') && (c != EOF))//loops until c == q (and c!=EOF)
    {
        c = getchar();//waits until stdin sees a "q", (i.e. from keyboard)

        //An EOF (-1) or `q` will exit the loop
        //any other input will allow execution flow to continue, 1 loop at a time.  
        //Add additional forking code here.           
        //for each loop, spawn a new thread.
        //All secondary threads spawned will run parallel to other threads.
    }
    //exiting here will kill all threads (secondary and primary.)
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, your parent process and child are running in parallel after fork,
You can see this by infinite looping child process and printing it's name while parent and other processes are doing the same.

2) Yes, here's how:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int i = 0;

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        if ((pid = getppid()) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "child error: getppid()\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (kill(pid, 9) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "child error: kill()\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            printf ("child %d\n", ++i);
        }
    }
    else if (pid == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: fork()\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        printf("parent %d\n", ++i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

3) If you need that specific pattern, you need interprocess communication and synchronization. Suggest [this](http://google.com)

Comment: LOL! A user comes to StackOverflow for guidance, and we should send them to Google. Thanks for the revelation. I'm pretty sure this isn't what up-votes are meant to encourage, but on the grand scale of things I reckon I can let my "lead by example" slide a bit. +1 for making me laugh, sir.

Comment: @Nick I find JonathanLeffler's answers-suggestions closer to my thoughts. Thank you too, for your reply.